# JTAG individual chip selection

Tags: jtag

Is it possible to select an individual chip from the chip structure in the picture below.
It also seems like the TDI is chained to the TDO in other chips. And the TMS is connected in parallel to all chips. So if you were to choose the bypass option wouldnt it be choosing the same option for all chips?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is,

As part of the protocol you can specify the number of devices before and after the one you want to communicate with. Likewise the number of bits in the IR registers of the devices before and after (cater for different chips with different register sizes)

By specifying the number before and after, as the JTAG commands are popped through the chain,the device matching this criteria is programmed

Comment: Ah so would the instruction register be responsible for selection of inidivual chips for communication?

Answer (score 0):

Each TAP in the chain has either IR or DR selected synchronously: all TAPs follow the same standard state machine you posted, and all of them have a copy of the same TMS signal.

When you are in Shift-IR state, TDI is shifted to a big shift register made of all IRs. When you are in Shift-DR, TDI is shifted to a concatenation of all DRs. TDO gets the output of said shift register. That's what makes TAPs chainable.

Each TAP has only one IR, and multiple DRs. IR is fixed in terms of length and function for each TAP, DR that is selected for Capture/Shift/Update-DR is determined by current IR. i.e. the value that was in the IR shift register when TAP went through Update-IR state.

As IRs are fixed in length, you can predict total IR length for the chain. Moreover, there is a standard mandatory instruction for any TAP called "BYPASS", that has (mandated by standard, again) to be encoded as all-ones instruction. When Bypass instruction is selected for a TAP, DR is mandated to be 1-bit long, and do nothing on Update.

When you want to exchange with only one TAP and ignore the others, you cannot make them disappear, but you can reduce them to IR=all-ones, DR=1-bit.

So, as JonRB noted, for a chain where only one TAP is interesting, all you need to know is its position in chain in terms of TAP number and IR offset in total IR chain.

For instance, in the chain with 6 TAPs you posted as illustration, if we assume all TAPs have 4-bit IR, and we want to communicate with chip#3, we'll have:

- Total IR length = 24 bits. When shifting an instruction to chip#3 and setting all others to bypass, we'll shift 24 bits of 0xffIfff (with I == instruction for chip#3), LSB first. For instance, let's say we shift IR=4 on Chip#3 and put others in bypass.

```
               Tap1 Tap2 Tap3 Tap4 Tap5 Tap6
    IR: TDI -> 6666 5555 4444 3333 2222 1111 -> TDO
    Value      1111 1111 1000 1111 1111 1111
    Semantics  Byp  Byp  Inst Byp  Byp  Byp
```

Here the only required information is TAP3 IR length, IR bits before and after in chain (here, 12 and 8). An equivalent way of presenting this is giving total IR length, target IR length and target IR offset from start of chain (here, 24 total bits, TAP3 at offset 12, 4-bit long)

- If we say TAP3 selected DR is 32-bit when IR=4, total DR will then be 37 bits long (3x 1-bit bypass registers, 32-bit DR, 2x 1-bit bypass). When shifting data to the TAP, you'll have to offset your 32 useful bits starting at bit 3 (counting from 0) over the 37 bit shift (i.e. data will start on the fourth shift cycle)

```
    Tap        1 2 Tap3                             4 5 6
    DR: TDI -> 6 5 44444444444444444444444444444444 3 2 1 -> TDO
    Data       - - XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX - - -
    Semantics  B B <Your useful register          > B B B
```

Here, the only needed information is TAP3 DR length and number of TAPs before and after in chain (here, 3 and 2).

Note: when shifting data to TDI of from TDO, what is shifted first is data from/to the end of chain (i.e. TAP closer to TDO).